# intellij idea concise simple try catch blocks

Tags: intellij-idea

I´m new to Intellij Idea and I´m trying to set my style of code in the first place. While doing so I tried to tell Intellij Idea that I want to have simple try-catch blocks as a single line of code for readability reasons.

Instead of this:

```
Statement statement = null;
if(statement!=null){
  try{
    statement.close();
  }catch(Exception ex){
    log.error(ex);
  }
}
```

I it to be automatically formated to this:

```
Statement statement =null;
if(statement!=null){
  try{statement.close();}catch(Exception ex){log.error(ex);}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can edit how the try/catch block appears by default, but what you can do is create a live template. Perhaps this would be of some use to you.

Go to: Settings -> Live Templates -> Add a template (plus sign). Fill in abbreviation, description. Add template text. I'm not an expert in how to create templates, but this seems to do the trick:

```
try{$SELECTION$} catch($EXCEPTION$ e){}
```

You can also click `edit variables` on the right, and add `name`, `expression`, `default value`. In the `name` field you want to add `EXCEPTION`. In the `Expression` field, add `subtypes("java.lang.Exception")`. In `default` field, add wanted default value, e.g. `Exception`.

Once you're done with it, click right mouse button on it and select `change context`. Select Java. You probably will want to modify it further for your needs - I am sure you will find better resources on how to write IntelliJ templates than with what I can come up now.

Once you have a live template, you can surround a code block by pressing ctrl+alt+j. Also, when you start typing `try`, a pop-up should show you a template you created.

I would also have a look at this [blog entry](http://arhipov.blogspot.lt/2011/07/whats-cool-in-intellijidea-part-ii-live.html). It should be a good starting place.

P.S.: Personally, I find expanded try catch blocks much more readable.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found a similar way to add a live template for defined cases.